# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11675148 byte allocation with 6

Tags: android, dpi

can anyone make sense of this error?  This is on a physical device, Android 6.0, however it works completely fine on a VD, 5.0.

Here is the error

```
Process: com.example.ericr.pokerquizzer, PID: 10884
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11675148 byte allocation with 6
at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:44
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2638)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2543)
at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:3
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatD
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatD
at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatRe
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppComp
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.ja
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.ja
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatVie
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInfl
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelega
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDele
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDe
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity
at com.example.ericr.pokerquizzer.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:37
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:113
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)

                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.jav
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Okay while I was typing this up, I did more research, and I discovered this problem to be something to do with image density?  However, my app works fine on a low density tablet (Nexus 9), and works on a high density virtual device, (Nexus 5), but crashes on a medium density Moto G3 (physical device).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use an image loading library to mitigate this issue

Comment: @ZUNJAE Highly unlikely to actually help.  You have no idea if he has memory leaks, if his issue is with loading images, or if his problem is just using too large of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimize images before adding them into android project, you can do that using free software like RIOT, and also make sure that if youre doing image calls from urls they be always singleton

Comment: What do you mean optimize? And I don't completely understand the term singleton.  I have a method that updates the image views upon a certain click listener, on the same activity.

Comment: Riot minimizes the size of the img without loosing too many quality, also you're using this plugin to add assets to your project? https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer

Comment: problem was solved I was using HUGE images and then scaling them down in the app.  So now theyre just low quality to begin with.  lol I'm pretty new to this stuff as you can tell